# C# convert int to hex int

Tags: c#

Ok, so everyone says to use:

```
// Store integer 182
int intValue = 182;
// Convert integer 182 as a hex in a string variable
string hexValue = intValue.ToString("X");
// Convert the hex string back to the number
int intAgain = int.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

But this doesn't work however. This is the answer everytime someone asks, but when I do this, my integer still gets converted back to decimal.

This isn't a duplicate question because every other question had the wrong answer because this doesn't actually work. What is the real way to convert an int into a hex int? Doing this just keeps intAgain as decimal 182.

Comment: intAgain is supposed to be a decimal. Your HEX value in in hexValue ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is self-answering. The desired result is already in the posted code in `hexvalue`. The poster is confused because of the lack of understanding of value versus presentation.

Comment: Did you miss one more language tag [tag:malbolge]  maybe?

Comment: Why do you think `intAgain` is a decimal? It's clear that it's an *integer*, from `int.Parse` and the fact you've defined your variable as an integer. The hex representation is stored in `hexValue`. Can you please explain what exactly you're trying to do here?

Comment: It is just the way vs is displaying the results.  The two numbers are equivalent.  If you are viewing results in a watch window you can change the value type by right clicking on the column header.

Comment: I don't want a hex string. I wan't an integer that is hexidecimal. You can't use strings with binary readers BaseStream.Position

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `int intValue = 182;` you allocate 32 bit in memory (4 byte).
Since a memory can store only binary values, you store 182 in memory like this:

```
00000000 #Byte 1
00000000 #Byte 2
00000000 #Byte 3
10110110 #Byte 4
```

When you do `string hexValue = intValue.ToString("X");`, you allocate in memory an array of chars to represent a string.
Number 182, in hex is B6.
Each char is stored a binary and is set to a digit of number B6.
The chars to be saved as binary in memory are encoded with UTF-16 standard ( 2 Byte per char are needed).
Sample of memory representation of variable hexValue

```
   01000010 #Byte 1 (char 'B') 
   00000000 #Byte 2
   00110110 #Byte 3 (char '6')
   00000000 #Byte 4
```

With `int intAgain = int.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);` you convert again the string to a number:

```
00000000 #Byte 1
00000000 #Byte 2
00000000 #Byte 3
10110110 #Byte 4
```

The type int doesn't store the numerical base, store only the value as binary in memory, hex or decimal is only a way to represent the value, and this can be done only when you convert the value in a readable string.

Comment: A `char` in C# (`Char` in .NET) is a UTF-16 code unit, one or two of which encode one Unicode codepoint, depending on the codepoint. "B" needs one UTF-16 code unit, as does "6". Your explanation would be valid if you accounted for that. (BTW—UTF-16 is used by .NET, Java, JavaScript, XML, HTML,…. Many, many mentions of ASCII are just plain wrong.)

Comment: @Tom Blodget, thanks I fixed the answer, please can you confirm if I placed correctly the Bytes order?